# Avoiding type errors when passing objects or pointers as interface parameters

Tags: go

I recently tracked down a bug in my code where I'm basically confused why Go doesn't protect me from it. The code is roughly this (MCVE below):

```
// common interface for events
interface Event ...

// concrete event type
type ConcreteEvent ...

func EventHandler(e Event) {
    // check if the event has a specific type and treat that differently
    c, ok := e.(ConcreteEvent)
    if ok {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

ce := ConcreteEvent{...}

// two calls to the event handler that are both accepted by Go
EventHandler(ce)
EventHandler(&ce)
```

The first thing that is weird is that both calls are accepted. Ok, as far as I'm concerned, there is no doubt about the meaning, so why not accept both. However, and that is my main concern, the second one will *not* enter the `if` branch inside `EventHandler()` but the `else` branch. The behaviour switches between the calls if I change the check to `c, ok := e.(*ConcreteEvent)`.

My gut feeling is that this is a glitch or bug in the design of Go. However, changing it would change behaviour of existing code, which makes it difficult or impossible to fix in version 1. However, that's not my main concern, which is rather to find these cases and to avoid this error. So, are there any ways (or coding strategies) for avoiding this or at least becoming aware of it?

### MCVE

#### Code

```
package main

import "fmt"

// common interface for events
type Event interface {
    Value() int
}

// concrete event type
type ConcreteEvent struct {
    val int
}

func (e ConcreteEvent) Value() int {
    return e.val
}

func EventHandler(e Event) {
    // check if the event has a specific type and treat that differently
    _, ok := e.(ConcreteEvent)
    if ok {
        fmt.Println("ConcreteEvent")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("general Event")
    }
}


func main() {
    ce := ConcreteEvent{
        val: 42,
    }

    // two calls to the event handler that are both accepted by Go
    EventHandler(ce)
    EventHandler(&ce)
}
```

#### Output

```
ConcreteEvent
general Event
```

Answer (score 4):

The method set of a pointer type `*T` includes the methods declared on the value receiver:

Specs, [Method sets](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_sets)

> The method set of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods declared with receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the method set of T)

So both `ConcreteEvent` and `*ConcreteEvent` implement the `Event` interface.

This is not a "bug" in the language. In fact, it's properly documented. To avoid this issue, you either:

- declare the method with the pointer receiver, so that only pointer types will implement the interface
- or if both types are always valid, you can type-switch with the double case:

```
    switch t := e.(type) {
    case ConcreteEvent, *ConcreteEvent:
        fmt.Println("ConcreteEvent", t.Value())
    }
```

Note that in the double case, the type of `t` is `Event`.

Comment: Thanks for this response. I think I can word my question better by now. I think one surprising consequence of Go's design is that `*T` has the same interface as `T`  (plus possibly more), so in that light, a `T` can be substituted with a `*T`. However, checking if something is a `T` doesn't work when applied to a `*T`, which seems kind-of inconsistent.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt for how I see it, this is consistent with the fact that a field or method call `v.Foo` is shorthand for `(*v).Foo` as appropriate. Anyway, that’s how the language is designed

Comment: So, even though "The method set of the corresponding pointer type *T [...] also contains the method set of T", you wouldn't expect `val.(T)` to tell you about that when `val` is a `*T`? I could understand that it does exact type matching, if this wasn't also used to check whether an object implements an interface. That said, you're right, we'll have to live with that until at least Go 2, probably. Maybe that will give us a `val.(interface T)` which works for both `T` and `*T`?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt *you wouldn't expect val.(T) to tell you about that when val is a `*T`* — hmm, not really, no. I expect a type assertion to tell me whether the value boxed in the interface is exactly type `T`, which is != `*T`. If with Go2 you mean type params, the assertion with `T` as type param will match exactly on the type used to instantiate the generic, so it *may* help alleviate this issue

Answer (score -1):

> So, are there any ways (or coding strategies) for avoiding this or at least becoming aware of it?

No. This is a non problem.

Comment: While a simple "No" is an answer (not necessarily a correct one though), declaring this as "a non problem" is a bit condescending and not helpful at all.